# How in-line link URL with ) and # in Reddit?

Tags: reddit

Consider URL with # after bracket like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life.

I can inline link on Stack Exchange. For example, the following markdown will properly render as [Inline Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life) on SE:

```
[Inline Link](https ://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life)
```

On Reddit instead of [Inline Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life) i get:
[image: Reddit link doesn't include the bookmark in the link]

Answer (score 1):

You'll only have this issue in Old Reddit which interprets any closing parentheseses `)` as the closing delimiter of a URL.

New Reddit interprets Markdown links differently and will allow unescaped parentheses in the URL portion of a link.

#### Example Markdown Link Rendering

For the Markdown code that follows, the table below shows the differences in rendering.

```
[Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life)
```

##### Rendered in Reddit

| Reddit | Rendered | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Old** ver. | `Test#Early_life)` | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran |
| **New** ver. | `Test` | [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life|](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_(American_veteran)#Early_life%7C) |

Comment: @Blindspots I did a quick test on a reddit comment. It displayed correctly on the new reddit but not on the old reddit. I had to delete the test though.

Comment: Maybe use a [subreddit like r/sandboxtest](https://www.reddit.com/r/sandboxtest/)

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. Parentheses are reserved characters and should be percent-encoded when they conflict with use as a delimiter. 
    
   The Markdown link with percent-encoded parentheses `%28` and `%29` would be:

   ```
   [Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brown_%28American_veteran%29#Early_life)
   ```
2. Markdown is not a coding language but a family of many different text markup implementations that can behave differently in subtle and not-so-subtle ways. Stack Exchange has its own variant and Reddit has their own custom versions for each of Old and New Reddit.

## Learning Resources

- [Babelmark, Compare Markdown against different implementations](https://babelmark.github.io/)
- [John Gruber's Markdown (the first first markdown-to-html converter)](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)
- Stack Exchange's [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp)
- [Snoomark, New Reddit's Custom Markdown](https://reddit.com/r/reddit.com/w/markdown)
- [CommonMark, a highly compatible specification of Markdown](https://commonmark.org/)
- [List of CommonMark Implementations](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark-spec/wiki/List-of-CommonMark-Implementations)
- IETF RFC 3986 Standards:
   [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)
- IETF RFC 7763 Informational:
  [The text/markdown Media Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763.html)

Answer (score -1):

The `#` after a path refers to the DOM Element with the id following the `#`.

The only reason for this not to work on Reddit is, if they somehow don't allow links containing the `#` character. In this case, there is no way for you to specifically link to the id.